# setTimeout function parameters undefined (JS)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have not been able to find a proper explanation to this.

```
function subtract(x, y) {
    setTimeout(function(x, y) {
      document.write(x - y);
  }, 1000);
}

subtract(1, 1);
```

This writes NaN to the document because the x and y parameters passed to setTimeout are undefined. You'd think that x and y should be integer 1 and it's within scope of the subtract function. The following snippet works perfectly fine and writes integer 0 as expected:

```
function subtract(x, y) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.write(x - y);
  }, 1000);
}

subtract(1, 1);
```

Removing the parameters seem to solve the problem. Why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Your were shadowing variables, maybe this may help: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow

Comment: Just leave the `x, y` out of the `setTimeout()` callback function.

Comment: this article might help 
https://coderbyte.com/algorithm/3-common-javascript-closure-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not passed the parameters to the function callback, when the callback is eventually invoked by the `setTimeout` the `x` and `y` are `undefined`.

So you see `NaN` as the output because `undefined - undefined` is `NaN`.

`setTimeout` takes the parameters of the function callback you have passed after the `delay` argument, in your case after `1000`.

Without passing the parameters, the `x` and `y` variables is scoped to the function callback. It won't take the values from the outer scope as it is shadowed by the function parameters you have given.

```js
function subtract(x, y) {
    setTimeout(function(x, y) {
      document.write(x - y);
  }, 1000, 1, 1);
}

subtract(1, 1);
```

You can also use `Function.prototype.bind` to pass the parameters to the callback function.

The `bind` takes the `this` context as the first argument and the rest of the arguments are the parameters to the function. In my example I have given `null` as the `this` context:

```js
function subtract(x, y) {
    setTimeout(function(x, y) {
      document.write(x - y);
  }.bind(null,1,1), 500);
}

subtract(1, 1);
```

Comment: This should work, but IE9 and older (I know, really old) won't pass extra parameters to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Its a javascript reference issue
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Under -- The "this" problem section they mention the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because of closures, asynchronous functions and execution context.
 settimeout is asynchronous function means it doesn’t wait or block the execution.
Settimeout function get executed by eventloop tick.
When you don’t pass arguments to function in it then it enclosed the values from subtract function and store it to use at the time of execution. This is because of concept of closures.
In case if we pass arguments, it no longer behave like a closure and expect arguments at the time of execution which is null. So you get NaN.
For experiment, pass default arguments to function in settimeout and check.